Dynamically resizing Squarespace's Gallery section to each images width and height using Javascript
I have a Squarespace site with a decent amount of custom CSS edits focused on simplifying (visually) the slideshow gallery.  I have it mostly set up as I'd like except the captions do not anchor to the bottom of the images with a consistent spacing on all images. Chrome's dev mode seems to show the container div's width and height are set in the HTML style tag based on the max-width/height of the list of images contained in the slideshow. As far as I can tell this requires a JS approach since Squarespace's CSS inject can't target the in-line html style.
My goal is for the gallery container to resize based on each images specific width and height so the caption placement is close to the image and consistent across all images.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?
Website URL
The caption spacing issue is most obvious on very tall or very wide viewports.

I am unsure if I understand you correctly, you basically want that the images are displayed in their original size?

@Snake_py Not exactly, I understand Squarespace uses a set of various resolutions or optimizations purposes; my goal is to have the container div for the gallery change size with the images size so the caption is displayed at the bottom of the image with a consistent 1vh or so buffer between the image and it.
This behavior is most obvious when vertical images are displayed after a horizontal, you can see that the caption stays in the same spot from the horizontal images; I want the caption to be right below the horizontal images like it is for vertical images.

I cannot reproduce the problem. All images are displaying at the full gallery height, with the caption directly beneath.

@BrettDonald Resize the window, the problem will show up.  There will be different spacing between the image and caption for vertical and horizontal images.

Okay, yes, in a tall viewport the problem is evident. The problem arises because the top-level wrappers .gallery-slideshow and .gallery-slideshow-wrapper have specific dimensions, and all their descendants simply stretch themselves to fit/fill those dimensions, including the img element which is styled with object-fit: contain. What you’d need to do instead is to set the image to the dimensions you want, or use its intrinsic dimensions, and allow its containers to fit themselves to that. Personally I’d be looking for another gallery widget, or building my own.

@BrettDonald yeah, that's the problem exactly.  Personally I like the function of this slideshow and obviously it being squarespace's gallery allows easily file management through their UI.  I know that JS can be easily injected and can be used to do things CSS cannot, specifically altering  tags but I have virtually zero experience with JS and in the many hours of googling I can't seem to find someone with a similar enough problem to glean a functional workaround. I have considered building my own site but I really don't like the notion of ditching the store already implemented/paid for

@Nightman and simply unsetting the height of .gallery-slideshow-wrappre { height: unset; } is not doing the trick for you?

@Snake_py Tbh, I didn't know unset was a thing, but it doesn't seem to work. Applying it to .gallery-slideshow-wrapper sets the container to 0px and applying it to .gallery-slideshow img does alter the element.style of the to "unset" but the overall container is not filling to that size.  It's late so maybe I still need to mess with it further but it seems like I need to somehow call up the size of each individual image and dynamically resize the container div to those dimensions?  Unset also does not seem to scale well across different viewports.

@Nightman, there is certainly a js solution here, but from what I understood now you baiscally want that the capition always sticks to the bottom of the image, while the image fills up as much height as possible for given width (without image distortion)?

@Nightman I believe that what you want is a relatively common need in Squarespace, but that perhaps your definition of it is unconventional. Is it correct that, on gallery pages 1) the gallery should take up as much of the viewport as possible 2) images should not be cropped; each image should show in in its entirety, and 3) each image should be as large as possible, given its aspect ratio. If that's correct, JS is not necessary. I believe your custom CSS has made a bit of a mess of things. If you can provide a gallery page without all your custom CSS, I can provide a CSS-based solution.

@Brandon Of your list only 2 is in line with my goals.  I want the images to be max 1300px wide, and then dynamically scale to be appropriately sized within the aesthetic bounds of the site layout.  I work on a 4k monitor but have been testing on other devices and also by changing viewports in my browser.  I have the sizing of the images as I want it essentially but as it is now the only viewport that works correctly as Brett Donald pointed out is a 4:3 monitor/viewport.  If you go into 16:10 or a taller viewport the problem sticks out.  Basically I would like to have all images displayed...

@Brandon ... as centered in the layout and at a similar resolution if possible (1300px) with the caption directly below the image.  This would mean the caption actually moves with each image vs. being completely static as it is now.

@Snake_py Yes exactly, I'm looking to have the images max out at 1300px on the long side OR say 90vw / 70vh if on smaller viewport.  In my custom CSS I used 'min()' to accomplish the dynamic sizing.  As it is, I am fine with the sizes of the images and have also implemented JS to max out the 'srcset' choice to ensure sharper images.  Basically the only thing I am unable to do is have that stupid caption dynamically move with the bottom edge of the images.  I honestly have thought about just adding it into the images themselves to save time but that's not very elegant / kinda janky haha.

@Nightman Thanks for the clarification; a 1300px max width is good to know, and also ancillary to the necessary code. JS is not needed to achieve what you have now. Using object-fit:contain precludes a consistently placed caption with CSS alone. I do suspect your aim could be accomplished with just CSS, possibly at the cost of loading larger-than-needed images. Or, indeed, one could use JS to calculate caption position based on standard Squarespace img attributes. As it is, the additional CSS/JS makes proposing a cleaner solution rather difficult.

@Brandon I could probably concede the larger images being loaded and 'object-fit:contain' was really just me throwing darts at the wall trying to figure out how to achieve my goals.  I am not the most adept with CSS/HTML and Squarespace's implementation is not the most user friendly to say the least.
What would you recommend to get the captions behaving as I'd like?

@Nightman, if you provide the site witout yur added styling, I think I or somenonelse can provide the css you need. Right now I am mostly battling styles which I belive come from your attempts. Can you please remove all of the custom stylings regarding the galaray and then ping us here again. What you want is doable with css and if really not I can also provide a js snippet.

@Brandon Ok I disabled ALL CSS styling and JS code injections so it should be just straight default squarespace styling right now.

@Snake_py Ahh sorry, I tagged the wrong person! I disabled ALL the CSS and JS on the site.  It should be the default squarespace styling now.

@Nightman can you please check if this is enough?
.gallery-slideshow {   height: unset!important;   max-height: 75vh; }

@Snake_py That sorta works, the caption does have a similar amount of padding between each image but the vertical images are scaled down significantly in the process.  My goal is to have all the images be the same length on the long side and the caption will move up and down with the same amount of padding between the img and the caption on each img.  I left the styling you provided active on the page so you can see how it behaves.
By the way, thank you so much for the timely replies and trying to help me through this mess!

@Nightman, and you don't want that it becomes scrollable ?

I am looking at this right now (state-of-affairs img), and I am unsure where you want to expand it to, while keeping the aspect ratio and without overflowing. The handle for scaling right now is playing with the max-height and max-width (in conjunction with the image dimensions). At what screen size do you look at it?

@Snake_py Yeah I want to avoid scrolling completely in the galleries.  I think the problem is Squarespace calculates a size for the gallery-wrapper that will fit the aspect ratio best but remains static within the window (obviously it re-calcs when the window resizes) and this works by resizing all the vertical images to be smaller than the horizontal ones so that it fits well within the container.  This is the default behavior.  When I added all my CSS it exaggerated the caption padding because I am trying to get all the images to be the exact same length on the long side...

... but the container will not resize with it so since the vertical images are just as long as the horizontals on the long side it pushes the caption way down for the horizontals.  The goal is to remove this sizing behavior of the container by Squarespace and have the container auto resize to the preferred CSS styling of the img max(1300px,80vw).   That's why I think JS is necessary because I believe this styling behavior is an intrinsic part of Squarespace's framework and is overwritten by any injected CSS through their "custom code" function.

I think what I cannot wrap my head around is when you say, that all images should have the same length on the long side (width), this will destroy the aspect ratio of the image. If you would want to keep the aspect ratio you would need to significantly inrease the height of potraits. Unless you mean that we decrease the hieght of landscaped images so they fit to the size of the potraits.

@Snake_py By same length on the long side I mean width for horizontal or height for vertical. For example, all horizontal images are 1300 x 1036px and all vertical images are 1036 x 1300px.  As it is now, the vertical images would be scaled down to 826 x 1036px while the horizontal images are the correct 1300 x 1036px.  Essentially I want to have the images all be the same size and the container would resize to fit each image upon load and the caption will move up and down accordingly.

@Nightman I see - this is what I hadn't understood. Are you able to apply additional classes to horizontal or vertical images? In addition, please add back your css and js. I will try to figure out a small js snippet for resizing the container. Is probably the fastest way now to do it

@Snake_py Unfortunately I don't think Squarespace allows that functionality, the custom CSS feature is really just a small text box that augments the existing CSS; it's really quite rudimentary. Unless there is some specific CSS syntax I'm unfamiliar with to add classes I think JS is the only way to affect element.style.  I'll add my code back in right now, thanks again!

@Snake_py Just wondering if you had any time to figure out a JS solution to my problem here? All good if not, was just checking in.
